# Jbehave cant locate more than one story

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, jbehave

I have a Jbehave and selenium project in eclipse using maven.initially i was doing it for one story but now i have written two stories and i want that two stories to be run in tests.but only one story file is locating by the program.how can i locate all the story files in the folder resources?

here is my code so far
Google.java

```
public class Google extends JUnitStory {
@Override 
public Configuration configuration(){
    return new MostUsefulConfiguration().useStoryLoader(
        new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass()))
        .useStoryReporterBuilder(
            new StoryReporterBuilder().withCodeLocation(
                CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this
                    .getClass())).withFormats(    
                Format.CONSOLE, Format.TXT, Format.HTML, Format.STATS))
                ;    
}

@Override 
public List<CandidateSteps> candidateSteps(){
    return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), 
        new GoogleStep()) //can put in a comma separated list of Step implementers here
        .createCandidateSteps();
}
protected List<String> storyPaths(){
   return new StoryFinder().findPaths(
        CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()), 
        "*.story", "");
```

GoogleStep.java

```
public class GoogleStep {

private WebDriver driver;
private FluentWait<WebDriver> fWait;

public GoogleStep() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Program Files\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
    File pathToBinary = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");

    FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setCapability("moz:firefoxOptions", options.setBinary(ffBinary));
    WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    driver = driver2;

    fWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).pollingEvery(500, 
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).withTimeout(10,  TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

//Google Mapping

@Given("I navigate to google.lk")
public void navigateToGoogle(){
    driver.get("https://www.google.lk/");
    fWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("lst-ib")));
}

@When("I perform a google search for $query")
public void performASearchForGoogleQuery(String query){
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(query);
}

@Then("I click google Search Button")
public void clickSearchGoogleButton() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Google Search']")).click();
}

@Then("A google link $text exists in the results")
public void linkContainingTextExistsInTheGoogleResults(String resultText){
    driver.getPageSource().contains(resultText);
}

//yahoo mapping

@Given("I navigate to yahoo.com")
public void navigateToYahoo(){
    driver.get("https://www.yahoo.com/");
    fWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("uh-search-box")));
}

@When("I perform a yahoo search for $query")
public void performASearchForYahooQuery(String query){
    driver.findElement(By.id("uh-search-box")).sendKeys(query);
}

@Then("I click yahoo Search Button")
public void clickSearchYahooButton() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='uh-search-button']")).click();
}

@Then("A yahoo link $text exists in the results")
public void linkContainingTextExistsInTheYahooResults(String resultText){
    driver.getPageSource().contains(resultText);
}
```

And i have two story files named as google.story and yahoo.story

my folder structure is as follows

[image]

What am i doing wrong here or what i have to do?any help would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it:

```
@Override
protected List<String> storyPaths() {

    URL searchLoc = CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass());

    return new StoryFinder().findPaths(searchLoc, Arrays.asList("**/google.story",
                                                                "**/yahoo.story",
                                                                ""),
                                                  Arrays.asList("**/excluded*.story"));

}
```

The extra element in the first array list is probably not necessary, but I include it because the example I originally got my information from did it that way, but I can add several stories this way, just add more elements for each new story, and if I want to make a run of just one story, I can precede each story I don't want to run with comment double-slashes (//) i.e.

```
    return new StoryFinder().findPaths(searchLoc, Arrays.asList("**/google.story",
                                                                //"**/yahoo.story",
                                                                ""),
                                                  Arrays.asList("**/excluded*.story"));
```

Would only run google.story.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Bill Hileman. but i tried it this way and still its running only the google story.can't figure out the reason behind it.any guess why is it happening?

Answer (score 1):

Found out what was i doing wrong.I was extending the class from JUnitStory.JunitStory class doesn't allow you to override storyPath method.but for running multiple stories i have to extend it from JUnitStories and override Storypath method.Doing this Solved my problem.Thank you bill for your answer again.

Comment: My testrunner also extends JUnitStories.  I was not aware that there was a singular version (JUnitStory)  I'll know not to make that assumption again.  Thanks for sharing your update.